# The right approach to add window event listeners in the functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

It's pretty easy to add event listeners in the functional component:

```js
const Component = () => {
   const handleScroll = () => {
      // body
   }

   useEffect(() => {
       window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
       return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
       }
   }, [])
}
```

But it's okay if `handleScroll` doesn't change. Sometimes it changes a lot (due to props change, state changes and etc.) and it should be added to `useEffect` dependencies list:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
   return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
   }
}, [handleScroll])
```

Is it a normal practice to add and remove window listeners on almost each render of the component? Maybe, it's the situation when it's better to use class components that have an internal state?

Answer (score 0):

You should always pass `handleScroll` in the `useEffect`s deps array.

Then, ways to limit re-rendering include wrapping `handleScroll` inside a `useCallback` and using `ref`s.

Based on your limited example, not knowing for sure, but the `ref` approach in the `useEventCallback` example from the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) might be helpful for your situation.

```
import { useEventCallback } from './myHooks'

function Component() {
  const [myChangingState, changeIt] = useState()

  const handleScroll = useEventCallback(() => {
    // body uses `myChangingState`
  }, [myChangingState]
)
```

which will keep it from updating on every render.